# Having issue while implementing recursion

Tags: python, recursion, python-os

I'm trying to move the files from one source directory to another destination directory considering the destination directory has the same file and folder structure as the source directory.

source directory:

```
source/
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3
├── folder_a
└── folder_b
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3
```

destination directory:

```
destination/
├── file4
├── file5
├── file6
├── folder_a
└── folder_b
    ├── file4
    ├── file5
    └── file6
```

The script i'm trying to create:

```
import os
import shutil
from subprocess import check_output

os.chdir("/home/smetro/source/")
destination= "/home/smetro/Games/destination"
def mover(destination):
    for i in os.listdir():
        if os.path.isfile(i):
            shutil.copy(i,destination)
            print("file moved: {} to {}".format(i,destination))
        else:
            new_dir= check_output('pwd').strip().decode('utf-8')+"/"+i
            os.chdir(new_dir)
            destination += "/{}".format(i)
            mover(destination)
            
mover(destination)
```

whenever I'm running the script I'm able to move some files from source directory to destination directory. However, it throws `FileNotFoundError` error and I get the output as mentioned below:

```
file moved: file1 to /home/smetro/Games/destination
file moved: file3 to /home/smetro/Games/destination
file moved: file2 to /home/smetro/Games/destination
file moved: file1 to /home/smetro/Games/destination/folder_b
file moved: file3 to /home/smetro/Games/destination/folder_b
file moved: file2 to /home/smetro/Games/destination/folder_b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smetro/move.py", line 18, in <module>
    mover(destination)
  File "/home/smetro/move.py", line 14, in mover
    os.chdir(new_dir)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/smetro/source/folder_b/folder_a'
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the recursion in a wrong way or not able to use the OS module properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with recursion. The traceback shows you that the error didn't occur in a recursive call. It also has nothing to do with the `os` module.

The best hint is the path of the nonexistent directory: `folder_b/folder_a`. The issue is that you're looping over `os.listdir()`, but changing the working directory in the loop, so after cd-ing into `folder_b`, it tries to cd into `folder_a`, which isn't in `folder_b`.

I can think of a few different ways to fix that, but you'd probably be better off not changing the working directory at all. Instead, use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to walk the directory branch for you, as well as [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to simplify working with paths. To get you started:

```
from pathlib import Path

source = Path("/home/smetro/source/")
destination = Path("/home/smetro/Games/destination")
for root, _dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    root_rel = Path(root).relative_to(source)
    new_root = destination / root_rel
    for file in files:
        print(new_root / file)  # Just for demo
```

Comment: On second thought, it might make more sense to cd into `source` so that you can `walk('.')` and make `root` relative. LMK if you want me to write that out for you.

Comment: Thanks mate! I thought something is wrong with recursion but yes you are right it was just that I was still in `folder_b` and `folder_a` was not in there. I still wonder how `os.lisdir()` represent the files and folders.